# Como criar um layout de navegação?

Tags: android, xml

Gostaria de criar um layout navegação. Exemplo: tenho teclado com passar o dedo em movimento horizontal, ele troca o layout do teclado. Qual layout eu devo usar para realizar essa tarefa?

Se alguém puder me dar um exemplo, agradeço desde já.

Comment: Olha, pra mim não está nada claro qual é de fato a sua dúvida. É possível dar mais detalhes?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues a ideia é seguente tenho dois tipos de teclados feitos, cada um no seu layout, quando o usuário passar o dedo horizontalmente trocar de teclado que esta no outro layout. Não se essa opções consegue fazer, que são include Other layout ou fragment. Não sei se foi claro.

Comment: Rodolfo, você quer algo semelhante ao [`ViewPager`](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) ou algo mais sutil onde você detecta o `Fling` e muda o layout? Se for o segundo caso você pode usar um [`GestureDetector`](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html)

Comment: @Wakim sim essa é a ideia